# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No storage mechanism for clients specified'

Tags: asp.net

IdentityServer4 with Asp.Net Core 2.0 application run time error.
i am using `visual studio 2017`.i try to run the application for console, i get this error for "`Statup.cs`" this method `"app.UseIdentityServer();"` error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No storage mechanism for clients
>   specified. Use the 'AddInMemoryClients' extension method to register a
>   development version.'

Comment: Did you try using `AddInMemoryClients`?